# How to convert generic sequence into triangle using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, combinatorics, pascals-triangle

If I have a sequence `IEnumerable<T>` (not numbers, just `T`):

```
[ a, b, c, d ]
```

How to return sort of Pascal's or Floyd's triangle:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
```

so it would be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`?

Wondering whether there a way to achieve this elegantly using LINQ rather than implement manually using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var seq = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var pascal = seq.Select(a => seq.Take(seq.IndexOf(a) +1 ).ToList());
```

edit:

```
var seq = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var pascal = seq.Select((a,i) => seq.Take(i+1).ToList());
```

Comment: This is pretty cute! You may want to mention an assumption that elements of the sequence need to be unique.

Comment: Would `Select((x,i) => ...)` do the same trick but in more efficient way?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method:

```
T[][] ToTriangle<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    var inputAsList = input as List<T> ?? input.ToList();
    return inputAsList.Select((t, i) => inputAsList.Take(i + 1).ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

From a console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = "Hello, world!";
    var output = ToTriangle(input);
    foreach (var set in output)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",set));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

(A string is an array of characters.)

> H
>   He
>   Hel
>   Hell
>   Hello
>   Hello,
>   Hello,
>   Hello, w
>   Hello, wo
>   Hello, wor
>   Hello, worl
>   Hello, world
>   Hello, world!

Comment: Hope you won't mind to give Etienne some extra points, since his/her solution was posted slightly earlier than yours spite being less effective initially.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in place of `for` loop lets you build a triangle with a single line of code:

```
var data = new string[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
var triangle = Enumerable.Range(1, data.Length).Select(row => data.Take(row));
```

`Enumerable.Range` serves as the outer loop; `data.Take(row)` serves as the inner loop.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BtPM2F)

Comment: Asking proper question is half way to the solution :) I got same but to avoid double sequence enumeration had to require `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` to know its length in advance. Wondering whether there is a way to accept `IEnumerable<T>` but still enumerate it just once.

Comment: Assuming an arbitrary sequence with Length = 4, I do not think it is a valid Pascal's or Floyd's triangle.

Comment: @Romoku: I'm not looking for valid Pascal's or Floyd's triangle, just didn't find a better way to explain what I'm looking for. Basically just a triangle.

Comment: @abatishchev Since you need to repeat the first entry `n` times, the second entry `n-1` times, the third entry `n-2` times, etc., there is no way to avoid repetition without "materializing" the sequence into an array or a loop.